# using coverity 2019.03

Tags: gcc, build, coverity, gcc9

I m using coverity 2019.03
After the configuration I have the message the Successfully generated configuration for the compilers: g++ g++-3 g++-4 gcc gcc-3 gcc-4 ld
but when trying to build , I have :
[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.
knowning that my project is compiled with gcc-9.2

what can be the problem ?

Tahnks

I tried to specify the verison of gcc9